# Rendering datatables in a for-loop

Tags: shiny, dt

I want to display multiple tables in a shiny-app, and as they should all behave the same, I thought I could render them in a for-loop:

```
library(shiny)

getData = function(name){
    if(name=='foo'){
        return(data.frame(foo=c('foo')))
    }else{
        return(data.frame(bar=c('bar')))
    }
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "foo"),
    DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "bar")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    for(item in c('foo','bar')){
        output[[item]] = DT::renderDT(getData(item))
    }
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Although the loop iterates correctly through the different 'datasets', all the tables finally show the same dataset ('bar' in the example above), notably the last one called in the loop.
It seems that the structure `output[[item]] = ...` doens't behave the way I think it should, but I can not figure out what is going on.

Thanks a lot!

[image: resulting app from the code above]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `local` as shown below

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  for(item in c('foo','bar')){
    local({
      item <- item
      output[[item]] = DT::renderDT(getData(item))
    })
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Tank you, indeed that works! 
I'm guessing the problem is that ```item``` is not reassigned to a new object, but the object is just altered in every step, and so all the tables end up pointing to the same dataset?

Comment: It is due to lazy evaluation.